# What are the rules of the locative case?

Tags: словоупотребление, падежи, узус, терминология

I understood the first time I heard about the locative that it was usually reserved for monosyllabic masculine nouns (ex. *чай*, *дом*, *сок*) with exceptions (*кровь*, *дверь*). However, I recently saw that *на  дому* is the correct usage for describing activities inside of a house, whereas *на доме* for activities on the roof.

But just today, I notice that the locative case isn't used once it is modified by an adjective? For example, I can find no record of the sentence *на моём дому* online, but instead, I see *на моём доме*. Are there any concrete rules to tell me when to use the locative, as what I am learning seems arbitrary.

Comment: I'm afraid there're no formal rules on the Vocative case, because in Russian it is only recognized by linguists and regarded by them as a relic of the Old Russian and as highly irregular, they still research it and don't have all the answers... The lack of its recognition manifests in its relegation to the Prepositional case as its 2nd form. I'd repost the link given below by @Sergey Slepov to a very instructive article by a linguist Plungian ["On the semantics of the Russian Locative (2nd Prepositional case)"](http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/plungyan-02.htm)

Comment: На дому is an adverb, just like "at home" (you cannot say "at white home")

Comment: чай and сок hardly have a locative case. I only can imagine expressions like настой на чаю and в самом соку. The later is a fixed idiom, and the first one sounds awkward.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But just today, I notice that the locative case isn't used once it is
>   modified by an adjective?

Not quite, it's totally correct to say

> На белом/рыхлом<sup>adj.</sup> снег**У**
>   На крутом<sup>adj.</sup> вал**У**
>   В горячем<sup>adj.</sup> бо**Ю**
>   В дремучем<sup>adj.</sup> лес**У**
>   На нашем<sup>poss. pron.</sup> век**У**
>   В новом<sup>adj.</sup> порт**У**
>   В дальнем<sup>adj.</sup> кра**Ю**
>   В цветущем<sup>adj.</sup> сад**У**
>   В липком<sup>adj.</sup> пот**У**
>   На своём<sup>poss. pron.</sup> х..**Ю**
>   В ночном<sup>adj.</sup> бред**У**

I'd argue that **дом** is unique, because its Locative has only survived for  limited use in а particular sense of `working from home`. In fact despite being written separately **на** + **дому**, semantically it functions as an adverb (which are to be written jointly with prepositions), because it can answer not only the question **`where?`** but also **`how?`**, and this i believe is the reason for its reversal to Prepositional case once this fossilized semantic unity is broken up by insertion of intermediate words.

Comment: I your answer I spotted one noun hat I had missed in my list of nouns with locatives.

Comment: @Anixx which one?

Comment: The obscene one.

Comment: @Anixx ah OK, i did have a feeling it could be the one )))

Comment: I wonder whether the word хер also has locative?

Comment: And хрен... I think as a plant it is the same as лён etc, so has the locative.

Comment: @Anixx i'd say it does, and i would absolutely say `на херу` if i meant it obscenely, as for plants i'm not sure, they are usually not thought of as places, `лён` i'd inflect as `на льне` , with `хер` i'm hesitant, don't know what the correct form is, both sound awkward to me

Comment: лён - во льну (if some kind of store of лён)

Comment: @Anixx agree, so it seems contingent on the preposition

Answer (score 6):

Locative is pretty much arbitrary indeed.

To further complicate things, some of the words which technically have locative only use it in set phrases or in certain senses.

*Дом* is one of such words. While *в дому* still can be understood, it has long since fallen out of use in live Russian speech, and *на дому* is a set phrase meaning "at home" in the context of work: *работа на дому* means "outwork" and *надомник* means "outworker".

You can't really say *на моём дому* nowadays.

Other words like this are *мир* (*в миру* can only be used in the sense of "secular world"), *щит* (*в щиту* means "in the electric panel") and several others.

Comment: **В щиту** must be a very slangy expression. I've never heard it, although I'm an electrical engineer.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, don't believe the other answers telling you that the locative is arbitrary and that there are no rules.

Locative is *not* arbitrary: for some words its use is *required*: **в глазу, в боку, в саду;** others (the majority) do not have a distinct locative form: **в столе, в городе.** It would be wrong to use them with the ending -у: **в столу, в городу;** and it would be wrong to say **в глазе, в боке, в саде.**

> Are there any concrete rules to tell me when to use the locative?

Short answer: Yes, there are a few trends. Read the long answer.

Long answer:

In the course of the last few hundred years Locative (and Partitive) were gradually phased out of the language. Some words have lost their locatives completely. E.g. my granddad (born 1929) would say "в отпуску". Nowadays  this sounds peculiar, "в отпуске" is pretty much the only way of saying it.

Some words are "hesitating" (to various degrees): мозг, счёт (на вашем счёте/счету осталось...), аэропорт, цех, мост (дырка в мосте / в мосту):

Some have split meanings:

> В углу комнаты лежит мяч.
> В прямом угле 90 градусов.
>
> На краю земли.
> В Краснодарском крае.
>
> В миру
> В мире

Others have only kept locatives in set phrases: на нашем веку (vs в двадцатом веке), на виду (vs в нетрезвом виде), на дому (vs на доме), час (в пятом часу vs в одном часе 60 секунд).

You are not finding any examples of "на моём дому" because "на дому" is a set phrase.

Most high-frequency words continue to hold on to their locatives quite firmly: час, глаз, бок, лес, снег, берег...

There are a few towns / villages called "Сосновый бор" and "Старый мост". I'd really like to hear how those people describe where they live!

Comment: More on this (if you can read Russian): http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/plungyan-02.htm

Comment: _I'd really like to hear how those people describe where they live!_ В «Сосновом боре», ествественно. То же самое, что «В лес**у** родилась ёлочка» vs. «В «Лес**е**» Островского …»

Comment: @user14830 И "в Старом мосте"? Это Ваше предположение или Вы как-то связаны с этими названиями?

Comment: Хм, поднял переписку вконтакте. Местные-таки говорят "в Бору", как мне писали. Но это разговорная речь, которая не обязана быть грамотной. "в Старом мосте" мне действительно режет ухо, но в "Сосновом боре" и "Лесе" не вижу проблемы.

Comment: Дырка в мосте - wrong, стоять на мосту - required. На вашем счёте - on your bank account, на вашем счету - among your achievements / on your record.

Comment: в саде много пользы для усадьбы - totally OK.

Comment: @Anixx, "уверен в мосте", "много пользы в саде" - these are examples of the regular prepositional case, not the locative. The preposition "в" in these cases does not specify a location.

Answer (score 1):

There are no rules for locative cases but rather sporadic usages that are evidence of having locative (to some extent) earlier.

Usages of phrases like `на дому`, `на снегу` etc. should be memorized and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this will be helpful, I haven't studied the Russian Language for at least 45 years or so. But I found this on another page:

https://www.clozemaster.com/blog/russian-genitive-case/

However, Russian doesn’t like us to keep us too comfortable, so some of these partitive genitives have different forms than their normal run-of-the-mill genitives. These genitive forms are used with verbs, receptacles and indefinite numerals.

```
Nominative  Genitive singular (normal)  Partitive genitive  Translation  
лук         лука                        луку                onion  
сахар       сахара                      сахару              sugar  
чай         чая                         чаю                 tea  
суп         супа                        супу                soup  
табак       табака                      табаку              tobacco
```

This happens largely with masculine nouns ending in consonants.
Have fun with that!

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE! You seem to be mixing up the partitive (a variant of the genitive) with the locative (a variant of the prepositional). The OP was asking about the latter.